# webpack bundling multiple css imports from js file

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

This is a part of my list of imports in my `app.js` file:

```
import "jsgrid"
import "./../node_modules/jsgrid/dist/jsgrid.css";
import "./../node_modules/jsgrid/dist/jsgrid-theme.css";
import "jstree";
import "./../node_modules/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.css";
```

and this is my `webpack.config`:

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
//var SplitChunksPlugin = require('webpack.optimization.splitChunks');
var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry:{
    app: [ './src/app.scss', 'jquery', './src/app.js']
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  externals: /^(tables.)/i,
  module: {
    rules: 
    [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'bundle-css.css',
            },
          },
          {loader: 'extract-loader'},
          {loader: 'css-loader'},
          {loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
            },
          },
          ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'bundle-sass.css',
            },
          },
          {loader: 'extract-loader'},
          {loader: 'css-loader'},
          {loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
            },
          }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: /src/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
        },
      }],
  },
  /*optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "initial"
    }
  },*/
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new LiveReloadPlugin({}),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' })
    /*new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: __dirname,
      manifest: require('./dist/vendor-manifest.json')
      })*/
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },

  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,

    //ignored: /node_modules/
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: './dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  }
};
```

Now the problem is that webpack only seems to take into account the first .css file in my list of imports, ignoring the rest.
So as of now, webpack would only compile `jsgrid.css` into my `bundle-css.css`. But if I comment this line: `import "./../node_modules/jsgrid/dist/jsgrid.css";` then webpack would only compile `jsgrid.theme` into my bundle.css. 
I have been searching for the issue for quite some time now, but have not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your config was totally wrong, see the changes i've done:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');   // <-------- run npm install --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin
const LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry:{
    app: './src/app.js'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  externals: /^(tables.)/i,
  module: {
    rules: 
    [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // <---- added here
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
            }
          }
         ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // <--- added here
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
            },
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: /src/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
        },
      }],
  },
  /*optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "initial"
    }
  },*/
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'style.css'
    }),
    new LiveReloadPlugin({}),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' })
    /*new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: __dirname,
      manifest: require('./dist/vendor-manifest.json')
      })*/
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },

  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,

    //ignored: /node_modules/
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: './dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately i didnt have the time to test it yesterday. But now I did. It was almost perfect. I only had to add my app.scss as entry point and then include the node_modules path to the postcss-loader since i am importing some scss from a plugin inside my app.scss.

Comment: your app.scss should be imported on your app.js. Putting them as entry points is not a good practice.